# Wamp appachy not changing version in wamp menu

Tags: php, mysql

I installed wamp on windows 8, i turned off the skype port 80, i used the desktop version of skype. Now i cant see my localhost or phpmyadmin. Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost.

I have two versions of appahy 2.2.17 and 2.2.11 i would like to use the 2.2.11 but wamp wont change my version in wamp menu. When i click its taking effect restart it but i cant see that the 2.2.11 is selected. I just think when i change the appachy to 2.2.11 the local will work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start Apache from the console and look at error.log, there might be something in there.

Comment: It was switching the version but its now showing it, now i use the 2.2.17 and its working. 
Thank you very much.